# Is it safe to TRUNCATE tables (catalogsearch_query, catalogsearch_fulltext, catalogsearch_result) in Magento 1.9.x?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a problem with SEARCHING in a Magento store. 
When I reindexing `catalogsearch_fulltext`, proccess is not completed I'm waiting more than 2 days and not result. The search not working correctly - don't return results.

I cheched the folowing tables in mysql

```
catalogsearch_query - ~3 000 000 records

catalogsearch_fulltext - ~300 000 records

catalogsearch_result - ~127 000 000 records
```

Is it safe to clear them?

```
TRUNCATE catalogsearch_query;
TRUNCATE catalogsearch_fulltext;
TRUNCATE catalogsearch_result;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes It safe to **Truncate these tables**

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/84430)

Comment: @liyakat / Ashish Jagnani - this qualifies as an answer. Consult the meta section for more info.

Comment: IF this qualifies as an answer can you upvote it

Comment: @SR_Magento, in answer should be some descriptive not only just like comment, if you agree you can just make coment or add some description why it is safe

Comment: @BKarthikKumar You do not up vote answers you don't think merit, actually its more appropriate for you to down vote if you don't like it.

Comment: @liyakat Yes it should - I've been through this in meta I agree with you 100%. It is an answer. That's why after all of you have flagged it is still here. I flagged a similar answer that literally said "Follow above step" and then a single line of what to add.  http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/answers-referencing-another-answer-for-the-same-question

Answer (score 8):

It's safe to truncate it but if you had previously created synonyms or redirects you will loose them.    Use

```
 DELETE FROM  `catalogsearch_query` WHERE  `synonym_for` IS NULL AND  `redirect` IS NULL`
```

and this will only delete rows that don't have a value in them for synonym or redirect